# What are the key indicator for Heroku apps to scale up web dyno

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I am using New Relic standard and Rails 3 on Heroku to build a web site. But not sure what indicators shown on New Relic should I keep an eye on to scale up the web dyno when certain criteria are met?

Say, indicator A comes to X level, I should add one Dyno to put it down.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Primarily you want to be looking at your logs and at the queue attribute on the heroku[router]  - if this starts going up (and importantly staying up) then you have too many requests that are being queued and can't be processed fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing long queue-wait times in the New Relic dashboard and there are no other good explanations (i.e. high variability in response times, use of Thin web server instead of Unicorn, etc.), that's generally a good indication requests are waiting in queue to be processed by a dyno.